# Does unordered_set::erase(pos) preserve the order of elements?

Tags: c++, stl, std, erase, unordered-set

I read in the standard of C++14 that the order of elements is preserved when using `erase(iterator pos)` of `unordered_set`.

I tried the following code with g++-6.2.0 and clang-3.9 (on linux though, this gcc's stdlib). Both should be able to handle that by the C++14-spec, I think:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
using std::unordered_set; using std::cout;

// output
template<typename Elem, typename Comp>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const unordered_set<Elem,Comp>&data) {
    for(auto &e : data) { os << e << ' '; } return os << '\n'; }

int main() {
  unordered_set<int> nums{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
  cout << nums; // MSVC: 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
  for(auto it = nums.begin(); it!=nums.end(); ++it) {
    if(*it % 2 == 0) {
      nums.erase(it);
    }
  }
  cout << nums; // MSCV: 9 1 3 5 7
}
```

Yes, the order of the elements is arbitrary. Here MSVC++ 19.00 had `9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10`. And after erasing all even elements the remaining elements are still in the same order `9 1 3 5 7`.

With g++ and clang++ though, I got a completely bad output of

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

which seems to indicate that the order of the elements was *not preserved* between calls but just... I don't know.

What is going on?

Comment: The standard has over 1000 pages of text. Saying you read it in the standard is not useful. Where in the standard did you read this?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that this cycle is wrong:

```
for(auto it = nums.begin(); it!=nums.end(); ++it) {
    if(*it % 2 == 0) {
        nums.erase(it);
    }
}
```

If *erase* is performed then *it* is invalidated and you cannot increment it. Presumably it causes the aforementioned behaviour.

You should use something like this:

```
for(auto it = nums.begin(); it!=nums.end();) {
    if(*it % 2 == 0) {
        nums.erase(it++);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use the return value of 'erase'.

Comment: @JesperJuhl only since C++11.

Comment: Which is 5 years old by now and should be the minimum standard (no, scratch that, C++14 should be) - but "yes" sure..

Comment: In some places (like my current job) C++03 is default. So I subconsciously use it as the default standard in some of my answers :) Obviously this question belongs to the land of C++1z, so the form of erase described by you might be preferable.